# Up button in SearchView of android

Tags: android, search, up-button

I have added a search view in my android app by using "android.support.v7.widget.SearchView",but it is not displaying the up button when i click on it.It is howing the X button.How to get the up button?

I am getting this image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WuqG.png)

but i want the below image which has an up button when click on the search view
and on click of up button search view should close
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy2vW.png)

Comment: will you please elaborate the question..

Comment: I have elabroated the question,please have a look

Comment: @Fargo- what is this "up button "? do you mean "up button "  in the keyboard?

Comment: The home button

Comment: @Fargo- On which device android version are you running your app?

Comment: Marshmallow but i want to have up home button for all versions

Answer (score 0):

See you can not have this home button thing in all version like the image you shared.
But you can do few tricks for it.

1. Check if you mobile version is lesser then Lollypop or not. If it is lesser, make a view similar to the image you shared at the bottom. And perform actions on it.
2. If you are not intersted in making any view, then you have to use

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) && webView.canGoBack()) {
       webView.goBack();
       return true;
     }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   ```

   }